# how to get data from outlook calendar?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

How I can get data events from Microsoft outlook calendar 
and put it in SQL database.
I have tried this code:

```
public class SamplesCalendar
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Outlook.Application msOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.NameSpace session = msOutlook.Session;
        Outlook.Stores stores = session.Stores;
        out
        foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
        {
            Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

            folder.GetCalendarExporter();

            Console.WriteLine(folder.FolderPath);

            folder.GetCalendarExporter();
            folder.Items.GetNext();
            LinkedList c = new LinkedList();
            Items CalendarItems = folder.Items;
            for (int i = 0; i <= folder.Items.Count; i++){
                c.AddFirst(1);
            }
            c.printAllNodes();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public Node next;
        public Object data;
    }

    public class LinkedList
    {
        private Node head;

        public void printAllNodes()
        {
            Node current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(current.data);
                current = current.next;
            }
        }

        public void AddFirst(Object data)
        {
            Node toAdd = new Node();

            toAdd.data = data;
            toAdd.next = head;

            head = toAdd;
        }

        public void GetAllCalendarItems()
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null;

            oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); ;
            CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
            outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem item in outlookCalendarItems)
            {
                if (item.IsRecurring)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.RecurrencePattern rp = item.GetRecurrencePattern();
                    DateTime first = new DateTime(2008, 8, 31, item.Start.Hour, item.Start.Minute, 0);
                    DateTime last = new DateTime(2008, 10, 1);
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem recur = null;

                    for (DateTime cur = first; cur <= last; cur = cur.AddDays(1))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            recur = rp.GetOccurrence(cur);
                            Console.WriteLine(recur.Subject + " -> " + cur.ToLongDateString());
                        }
                        catch
                        { }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Subject + " -> " + item.Start.ToLongDateString());
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I can't get any data from calendar. How do I call the methods to get the data?

Answer (score 1):

With this code you get all your items in your Outlook-calendar:

```
        var outlookApplication = new Application();
        NameSpace mapiNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        MAPIFolder calendar = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

        if (calendar != null)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= calendar.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var calendarItem = (AppointmentItem) calendar.Items[i];
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am find error with "Application()" word how I can fixed it

Comment: @diya I installed the nuget package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. Then it will be found. If not try to define it like this: new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application()

Answer (score 0):

You could read calendar data using the below code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace RetrieveAppointment
{
   public class Class1
   {
      public static int Main(string[] args)
      {
         try 
         {
            // Create the Outlook application.
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

            // Get the NameSpace and Logon information.
            // Outlook.NameSpace oNS = (Outlook.NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
            Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

            //Log on by using a dialog box to choose the profile.
            oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true); 

            //Alternate logon method that uses a specific profile.
            // TODO: If you use this logon method, 
            // change the profile name to an appropriate value.
            //oNS.Logon("YourValidProfile", Missing.Value, false, true); 

            // Get the Calendar folder.
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oCalendar = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

            // Get the Items (Appointments) collection from the Calendar folder.
            Outlook.Items oItems = oCalendar.Items;

            // Get the first item.
            Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppt = (Outlook.AppointmentItem) oItems.GetFirst();


            // Show some common properties.
            Console.WriteLine("Subject: " + oAppt.Subject);
            Console.WriteLine("Organizer: " + oAppt.Organizer);
            Console.WriteLine("Start: " + oAppt.Start.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("End: " + oAppt.End.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Location: " + oAppt.Location);
            Console.WriteLine("Recurring: " + oAppt.IsRecurring);

            //Show the item to pause.
            oAppt.Display(true);

            // Done. Log off.
            oNS.Logoff();

            // Clean up.
            oAppt = null;
            oItems = null;
            oCalendar = null;
            oNS = null;
            oApp = null;
         }

            //Simple error handling.
         catch (Exception e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
         }  

         //Default return value
         return 0;

      }
   }
}
```

For more information, please refer to this link:

[Read Outlook calender details...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce4031da-7448-475f-bac6-d20e04072164/read-outlook-calender-details?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Thanks Alina   but how I can get this data from another calendar at outlook like "meeting room 1"

Comment: @diya You can use PickFolder() instead of GetDefaultFolder() there you can choose your folder. If you deubug it you can get the id of the folder. With the id you can get this folder with GetFolderFromID("yourId"). GetFolderFromID is also used at the same place in code.